# How can I increase the SOAP Data size limit of 65536

Tags: wcf

ihave this error "T**he maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded**"
I maximized the maxReceivedMessageSize but nothing goes well
the app.config is the service layer is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- Lors du déploiement du projet de bibilothèque de services, le contenu du fichier de configuration doit être ajouté au fichier app.config  
  de l'hôte. System.Configuration ne prend pas en charge les fichiers de configuration des bibliothèques. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Navigateur.SL.ParentService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Navigateur.SL.IParentService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Navigateur.SL/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="Navigateur.SL.VideoService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Navigateur.SL.IVideoService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Navigateur.SL/Service2/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="Navigateur.SL.EnfantService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Navigateur.SL.IEnfantService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Navigateur.SL/Service3/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- Pour éviter la divulgation d'informations de métadonnées, 
          définissez les valeurs ci-dessous sur false avant le déploiement -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- Pour recevoir les détails de l'exception dans les erreurs à des fins de débogage, 
          définissez la valeur ci-dessous sur true.  Pour éviter la divulgation d'informations d'exception, 
          définissez-la sur false avant le déploiement -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FamissimaEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/NavigateurModel.csdl|res://*/NavigateurModel.ssdl|res://*/NavigateurModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=HP\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Famissima;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

the app.config in the presentation layer is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IParentService" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000" />
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IVideoService" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000"/>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEnfantService" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000"/>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Navigateur.SL/Service1/"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IParentService"
                contract="ServiceReferenceParent.IParentService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IParentService" />
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Navigateur.SL/Service2/"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IVideoService"
                contract="ServiceReferenceVideo.IVideoService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IVideoService" />
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Navigateur.SL/Service3/"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IEnfantService"
                contract="ServiceReferenceEnfant.IEnfantService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IEnfantService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Can someone help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle large datasize you should have a ServiceBehavior and set the maxItemsInObjectGraph as below

```
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehavior>
```

Comment: Thanks anyway, i changed th app.config on the client side an it did worked fine
name="BasicHttpBinding_IParentService"  sendTimeout="00:05:00"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"